# Append a parameter to value of tag using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
<entry key="user">1234</entry>
<entry key="docname">abc.pdf</entry>
</properties>
```

I want to append the value passed from java code to the filename present in docname tag and transform it into a new xml file using xslt, the output xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
<entry key="user">1234</entry>
<entry key="docname">abc_1.pdf</entry>
</properties>
```

I am using the below xslt. The parameter id is being passed from java code.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:param name="id"/> 
  <xsl:variable name="newName" select="/properties/entry[@key='docname']"/>
  <xsl:template match="entry[@key='docname']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace($newName, $newName, $id)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>   
</xsl:transform>
```

The above xslt is replacing the value in docname tag. I want to append the id with an underscore before the extension (abc_1.pdf) instead of replacing the whole value.
Could someone please help me with this..

Comment: So which value do you pass in for the `id` parameter, the string `_1` or solely `1`?

Comment: I am passing 1 as value to the id parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on the complexity of the input data, if there is only one dot '.' in those file names then you can simply do

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(., '.'), '_', $id, '.', substring-after(., '.'))"/>
```

Or use

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\.\w+$', concat('_', $id, '$0'))"/>
```

to replace suffix at the end with the concatenation of `_`, the `$id` and the suffix.